# When should I consider using position for positioning elements rather than flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position, alignment

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #dn {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 2px solid #cd1313;
        }

        .box1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
            font-size: 24px;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dn" class="boxn">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto ducimus repudiandae inventore iste porro distinctio necessitatibus incidunt accusamus facilis obcaecati! hey namen 
        <div id="d1" class="box1">
            Child
        </div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque deleniti quibusdam quod praesentium, soluta harum alias aperiam hic voluptatum natus?
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have displayed the box1 as flex box. It allow me not only horizontally align the items (Child) inside it but also allow me to vertically align item along cross axis. Then I asked myself, why didn't I use the position to center the text?. So what could be the consequences?.
Is it because we can't apply position on text?, what if the item was a span box, can I apply position in it?.
If yes then won't it create a problem, since we have to use position absolute to make it responsive to boxn..
Long and irritating question , but it is important for me>

Answer (score 0):

When using position, you will have to define how many pixels you want on each side of the object in order to position it. This is just not very flexible. Imagine you have to measure/calculate/try how many pixels you want for each object for different screen sizes, it is possible, but takes a lot if time and effort. So flexbox is just a lot easier to implement.

With flexbox your content will also be more consistent. What I mean by that is that it will calculate for you how many pixels you need on each side of your object. This will reduce the chance of miss calculation. And thus all elements will be positioned the same way.